# Stored procedure with output parameters returns -1 in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I have a simple c# application that uses the `Entity Framework 5.0` and should call a stored procedure with output parameters. The problem is that it doesn't work, and instead, it returns -1.

The `c#` code that I have looks like that:

```
// Define the output paramaters
SqlParameter operatorID = new SqlParameter("@operatorID", SqlDbType.Int);
operatorID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
SqlParameter operatorCode = new SqlParameter("@operatorCode", SqlDbType.Int);
operatorCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var parameters = new List<object>();
parameters.Add(operatorID);
parameters.Add(operatorCode);

var noOutput = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC my_sp_name @operatorID, @operatorCode", parameters.ToArray());
```

The stored procedure looks like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp_name] 
( 
     @operatorID        int             OUTPUT 
    ,@operatorCode      int             OUTPUT
 )
AS
    SET @operatorID = 123
```

I know it doesn't make sense, but it's just for a test.

The problem after executing the `c#` code is that the `noOutput` value is -1 and the `operatorID` value is empty, where I expect it to be `123`.

Does anybody have an idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameters in query must be with **OUTPUT** keyword

```
var noOutput = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC my_sp_name @operatorID OUTPUT, @operatorCode OUTPUT", parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: Oh my GOD, are you kidding me? Thanks a lot! Adding the `OUTPUT` works fine, but I thought that it's not necessary since I have already defined them as output parameters.

Comment: You must write OUTPUT.I have the same issue in MSSQL in query with OUTPUT Keyword

Comment: I understand now. I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **"operatorCode.Value"** property. the result will be there after execution.

If not try to use the **CommandType.StoredProcedure** and then execute the command with the store procedure name along with the parameters. you will get the output